# My ViewPager is blank when I click back, Its not showing the list

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, onbackpressed

I have an issue where my view pager is showing blank fragment when I back press.
I have a grid fragment(consider Fragment A) where when I click on a button its navigates me to another grid fragment(Consider Fragment B),when I click on a button it navigates me to a ViewPager(Fragment C) which has three Slidingtabs. each Tab layout has a listview in which if I select an item it navigates me to another fragment(Fragment D).My problem is when I backpress from Fragment D the ViewPager sliding tabs(Fragment C) are showing  blank empty screen.Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue.

```
public class RetrievalListOperation extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
List<VehicleInfo> vehicleInfos=new VehicleInfoData().getVehicleData();
DataService dataService;
List<VinInfoDTO> retlist;


private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment RetrievalListOperation.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static RetrievalListOperation newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    RetrievalListOperation fragment = new RetrievalListOperation();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public RetrievalListOperation() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_retrieval_list_operation, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dataService=new DataService(getActivity());
    retlist=dataService.getRetrievalJobsForStatus("Open");
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.retrieval_operation_rview);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    RetrievalOpenAdapter adapter=new RetrievalOpenAdapter(retlist);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    rv.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecycleItemClickListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), new RecycleItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    final TextView vin=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ret_txt_VIN);
                    final TextView model=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ret_txt_model);
                    final TextView variant=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ret_txt_variant_no);
                    final TextView desc=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ret_txt_description);
                   // final TextView color=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ret_txt_color);

                    String VIN=vin.getText().toString();
                    Log.e("--Recycler onTouch VIN-", VIN);
                    JobsDTO det = dataService.getVehicleDetails(VIN);
                    String detail=det.JobID+" / SyncStatus: "+det.SyncStatus+" /Location Lat"+det.locationDTO.Latitude+" lng"+det.locationDTO.Longitude;
                    Log.e("---RetoPenList---", detail);
                    Bundle b=new Bundle();
                    b.putString("VIN", VIN);
                    b.putString("model", model.getText().toString());
                    b.putString("variant", variant.getText().toString());
                    b.putString("desc",desc.getText().toString());
                  //  b.putString("color",color.getText().toString());
                    b.putString("job id",det.JobID);
                    Log.e("---Bundle Values--", " MODEL: " + model.getText().toString() + " VARIANT :" + variant.getText().toString() + " DESC:" + desc.getText().toString() + " COLOR :" );
                    Fragment fragment=new RetrievalMapOperation().newInstance("a" ," b");
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack("RetrievalList")
                            .commit();

                    fragment.setArguments(b);


                }
            })



    );



}



// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}



@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

public class RetrievalOpenAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RetrievalOpenAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    List<VinInfoDTO> vinfo;

    RetrievalOpenAdapter(List<VinInfoDTO> vinfo)
    {
        this.vinfo=vinfo;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.operationscardlayout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder pvh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.vehicleNumber.setText(vinfo.get(position).VIN);
        holder.variantNumber.setText(vinfo.get(position).Variant);
       // holder.color.setText(vinfo.get(position).Color);
        holder.desc.setText(vinfo.get(position).Desc);
        holder.model.setText(vinfo.get(position).Model);
       // Log.e("--RetCOLOR--",""+holder.color.getText().toString());
       // holder.time.setText(vinfo.get(position).getTime());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return vinfo.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView vehicleNumber;
        TextView variantNumber;
        TextView model,color,desc ;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.operation_retrieval_cview);
            vehicleNumber=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ret_txt_VIN);
            variantNumber=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ret_txt_variant_no);
            model=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ret_txt_model);
           // color=  (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ret_txt_color);
            desc=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ret_txt_description);
           //time=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_srtime);

        }
    }
}
}
```

**RetrievalTabs.java**(slidinglayout)

```
public class RetrievalTabs extends Fragment {
NavigationDrawerActivity nav;
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
CharSequence Titles[] = {"Open", "WIP", "Complete"};
int Numboftabs = 3;
ViewPager pager;
FrameLayout frameLayout;
LinearLayout linear;
private TextView actionBarTitle;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
RetrievalPagerAdapter adapter;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment RetrievalTabs.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static RetrievalTabs newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    RetrievalTabs fragment = new RetrievalTabs();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public RetrievalTabs() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    View actionBarCustomView = getActivity().getActionBar().getCustomView();
    actionBarTitle = (TextView) actionBarCustomView.findViewById(R.id.head_text);
    actionBarTitle.setText("Retrieval");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_retrieval_tabs, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.retrieval_tabs);
            adapter = new RetrievalPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);
            pager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.retrieval_pager);
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);
            tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
            tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
                @Override
                public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                    return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);

                }
            });
            tabs.setViewPager(pager);
        }
    });

}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

}
```

**RetrievalPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class RetrievalPagerAdapter extends android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created
android.app.Fragment tab1, tab2, tab3;
FragmentManager fm;

MyApplication app;

public RetrievalPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, CharSequence mTitles[], int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.fm = fm;
    this.Titles = mTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = NumOfTabs;

}


@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return Titles[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NumbOfTabs;
}


@Override
public android.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {

    if (position == 0) {
        tab1 = new RetrievalListOperation().newInstance("a", "b");
        return tab1;

    } else if (position == 1) {
        tab2 = new RetrievalInProgressList().newInstance("a", " b");
        return tab2;
    } else {
        tab3 = new RetrievalCompletedList().newInstance("a", "b");
        return tab3;
    }
}

    public int getItemPosition (Object object) 
    { 
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your code where you are launching fragment D from the viewpager list item?

Comment: From where are you fetching the list in Fragment C? Can you post your code?

Comment: Im fetching my data from local DB

Comment: @Ravi Teja I have posted the code, the above code is one of my slidingtabs list fragment.In on touchlistener im navigating to Fragment D